# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'triangle' is defined

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring. I am getting

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'triangle' is defined

with a simple java app.

I am getting the following Error Msg

```
Jul 20, 2014 7:44:44 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@383118: startup date [Sun Jul 20 07:44:44 EDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 20, 2014 7:44:44 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@47eaec: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'Triangle' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at com.springDemo.main.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:22)
```

my contextBean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="triangle"  class="com.springDemo.main.Triangle1" >
        <property name="type" value="Equilateral" /> 
    </bean >

</beans>
```

DrawingApp.java

```
package com.springDemo.main;

import org.springframework.core.io.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DrawingApp {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    static String[] springConfig  = 
    {   
        "classpath::*/com/springDemo/main/contextBean.xml"           
    };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
        Triangle triangle =( Triangle )context.getBean("triangle");
        triangle.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: If looking at your code, I think nothing wrong except I won't put classpath:: but classpath:. I think you might have two contextBean.xml loaded at the classpath. The one you post is not the one loaded first in jvm. It is quite common mistake. If you can share your project (or at least your classpath), then we can know the real cause.

Comment: Another thing to mention is classpath:* will search from all dependencies jar. classpath: will search from your project only but not dependencies jar.

Answer (score 2):

You are *already looking in class path* using  `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` hence there is no need to add `classpath::*`.

Simply *remove* it and see your problem will be gone.

```
ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/springDemo/main/contextBean.xml");
```

---

You can try with `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` as well where you have to use `classpath:`

```
ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath:com/springDemo/main/contextBean.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two `:` in the classpath definition. try to remove on:

```
"classpath:*/com/springDemo/main/contextBean.xml"
```

Comment: If file is not found then it gives `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Have you tested it. It gives me `class path resource [claspath:] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`

Comment: no it is a guess. Can yu show your project structure?

Comment: It's clear from the code that where configuration and Triangle1 are stored.

Comment: have a look at my post.

Comment: Is it the complete Stacktrace or are there other stacktraces?

Answer (score -1):

It's likely that `contextBean.xml` is not being loaded by Spring. Try loading the context file directly, i.e. without wildcard and the aforementioned `:` character

```
context = 
   new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/springDemo/main/contextBean.xml" );
```

Comment: don't you think that you have edited your post to match with mine.

Comment: while I've removed the `classpath:`, it's not the issue here - `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` will work with or without the classpath prefix. What is a problem are the double : and * which causes the path to be invalid :)

Comment: I have posted my answer after testing. I doesn't work with classpath.

Comment: Thx folks:- looks like a rookie mistake

Comment: Directly loading context.xml worked. ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/springDemo/main/contextBean.xml" );